# Is it a good idea to add a link/reference to experience or relieving letters in CV?

Tags: cv, hyperlinks

The purpose of a company experience letter is to validate claims a job candidate makes about their skills and experience in their resume, cover letter, or Curriculum Vitae (CV).

Is it a good idea to add a link/reference to experience or relieving letters in our curriculum vitae?

Comment: Would they even ever get clicked on by a person going through a mountain of resumes?

Comment: Depends on the type of link. A link to a publication or a project page of a research project may be useful, but a link to a relieving letter is unlikely to be of interest.

Comment: In U.S. English I don't understand "relieving letter". Can you clarify, please?

Comment: @paulgarrett Don't know how accurate it is, but [this question on Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... and also to @Vladhagen's below. :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally have several links in my CV:

- **Links to my publications.** This allows for a reader to quickly find my publications without having to search.
- **A link to GitHub.** This allows for a reader to see the code that I have produced.
- **A link to LinkedIn.** This allows for a reader to interact with me on LinkedIn if they so choose.
- **A link to my Math Genealogy.** Just for interest's sake.
- **A link to my university page.** My university is sometimes confused with another university in the area (similar names...it's a long story). This is to clarify which university I am speaking of. And it lets readers see what my department is up to.

When I am looking at a CV, if it has a number of tasteful links, I am rather likely to click on them and see what they are about. (Excessive linking can be overkill and a distraction of course). I am never in a situation where I am having to go through hundreds of CVs at a time, so I usually have time to explore links. And even if your CV is in an environment where the reader does not have time to click on links, why would it matter if you had links? So they do not look at them. It's not the end of the world.

I personally would include links to resources that help support your CV. (Like I said, do not over do it). Even a relieving letter would be okay in some cases. If the reader is not interested, they don't have to click the link. It's that simple.  But for me, I honestly might click on a relieving letter and read it. If it reflected positively on the candidate, that would never be a bad thing in my mind.

Comment: As my comment above: is "relieving letter" also called "reference letter" or "letter of recommendation" or such?

Comment: @paulgarrett A relieving letter is a letter that an employer would give you when you leave service with them. It is a specific type of letter of recommend.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Vladhagen. Now I know! :)